# Easy way to append token key to request data for every request with React Query

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-query

I have to add a token that is created upon login and put in cookies into my request data to every fetch request I make.  I'm currently doing it by using a custom hook that will add it every time so I don't have to add it multiple times.  Is there an easier way?  Maybe with axios?

Here is my custom hook:

```
import { useQuery as useBaseQuery } from 'react-query';
import axios from 'axios';


const fetcher = async (url, options) => {
  const token = Cookies.get('TOKEN');

  const { data } = await axios.get(url, {
    data: { ...options, 'TOKEN': token },
  });

  return data;
};

const useQuery = (queryKey, query, options) => {
  return useBaseQuery(queryKey, async () => {
    return await fetcher(query, options);
  });
};

export default useQuery;
```

and is used like this:

```
import useQuery from './useBaseQuery';

const requestData = {
  method: 'GET',
  path: pathToUrl,
};

export default function useGetActionAlerts() {
  return useQuery('actionAlerts', '/bin/user', requestData);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use interceptor, from documentation

> You can intercept requests or responses before they are handled by then or catch.

https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors